# C# TPL Task propagate exceptions - Multi-level task

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

The `Run()` method (first block of code) makes a call to `GetImpairedNodesFromCASpectrumAsync()`, which in turn makes a call to `GetRoutersOn3GBackupNodeStatusesAsync()`.

Currently, if any of the tasks in `GetRoutersOn3GBackupNodeStatusesAsync()` fail (due to an exception), I get a very generic Exception in the `Run()` method that says the task was cancelled.

How can I ensure that any Tasks in my call stack end up returning the original Exception back to the run method, so that I can handle it there?

```
public override void Run(ref DevOpsScheduleEntryEventCollection events)
{
    // I want to be able to catch any exceptions thrown from tasks in GetRoutersOn3GBackupNodeStatusesAsync()

    Task<NetworkDeviceNodeStatus[]> CasImapairedNodesTask = 
                CasOperations.GetImpairedNodesFromCASpectrumAsync();
    Task.WaitAll(CasImapairedNodesTask);
    NetworkDeviceNodeStatus[] CasImpairedNodes = CasImapairedNodesTask.Result.ToArray();
}

internal virtual async Task<NetworkDeviceNodeStatus[]> GetImpairedNodesFromCASpectrumAsync()
{
#if DEBUG
    Debug.WriteLine("Entering GetNodesInCriticalCondition()");
    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();
#endif

    // Execute both tasks.  Throw an Exception if any errors.
    try {
        var nodesWithCircuitsDown = new List<NetworkDeviceNodeStatus>();

        Task<NetworkDeviceNodeStatus[]> getAlarmingRoutersStatusesTask = null;
        Task<NetworkDeviceNodeStatus[]> getActive3GRoutersStatusesTask = null;

        getAlarmingRoutersStatusesTask = GetAlarmingRouterNodeStatusesAsync();
        getActive3GRoutersStatusesTask = GetRoutersOn3GBackupNodeStatusesAsync();

        await getAlarmingRoutersStatusesTask;
        await getActive3GRoutersStatusesTask;

        var threeGNodeStatuses = new List<NetworkDeviceNodeStatus>();
        var offlineNodeStatuses = new List<NetworkDeviceNodeStatus>();


        // Check if any nodes were hard down, but quickly came up on 3G
        foreach (var status in getAlarmingRoutersStatusesTask.Result) {
            var threeGStatus = getActive3GRoutersStatusesTask.Result.
                FirstOrDefault(x => x.DeviceRetrievalId == status.DeviceRetrievalId);

            if (threeGStatus == null) {
                offlineNodeStatuses.Add(status);
            }
        }

        foreach (var status in getActive3GRoutersStatusesTask.Result) {
            threeGNodeStatuses.Add(status);
        }

        nodesWithCircuitsDown.AddRange(threeGNodeStatuses);
        nodesWithCircuitsDown.AddRange(offlineNodeStatuses);

        Trace.TraceInformation("{0} nodes with main data circuit down.", nodesWithCircuitsDown.Count);
#if DEBUG
        sw.Stop();
        Debug.WriteLine("Leaving GetNodesInCriticalCondition(). [" + sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds + "]");
#endif
        return nodesWithCircuitsDown.ToArray();
    } catch (AggregateException ae) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var e in ae.Flatten().InnerExceptions) {
            sb.Append(e.Message + "\n");
        }
        throw new Exception("One of more errors occured while retrieving impaired nodes.\n" + sb.ToString());
    }
}

virtual internal async Task<NetworkDeviceNodeStatus[]> GetRoutersOn3GBackupNodeStatusesAsync()
{
    List<Branch3GInfo> branchActive3GInfos = new List<Branch3GInfo>();

    var nodeStatuses = new List<NetworkDeviceNodeStatus>();
    Task<Branch3GInfo[]> getActive3GRoutersTask = GetNodesOn3GBackupAsyncInternal();
    NetworkDeviceNodeStatus[] deviceStatuses = new NetworkDeviceNodeStatus[0];

    Task getBasicInfoTasks = await getActive3GRoutersTask.ContinueWith(async x =>
    {
        branchActive3GInfos = x.Result.Where(y => y.Status == Branch3GInfo.Branch3GStatus.Active).ToList();
        Trace.TraceInformation("Found " + x.Result.Count() + " CAS Nodes on 3G backup.");

        foreach (var branchActive3GInfo in branchActive3GInfos) {
            await branchActive3GInfo.RouterInfo.GetBasicInfoAsync();
            Trace.TraceInformation("Retrieved ModelBasicInfo for "
                + branchActive3GInfo.RouterInfo.GetBasicInfo());
        }

    }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);

    await getBasicInfoTasks.ContinueWith(x =>
    {
        deviceStatuses = GetNetworkDeviceNodeStatuses(branchActive3GInfos.ToArray());
        return deviceStatuses;
    }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);

    return deviceStatuses;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using Task.WaitAll(CasImapairedNodesTask) when CasImapairedNodesTask is only a single task?

Comment: [Async Exception handling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997415(v=vs.110).aspx), Also are you sure your not seeing an `AggregateException`?

Comment: @BrandonKramer Old code, it used to be multiple tasks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is due to `ContinueWith`, which will cancel its continuation when the conditions are not met (i.e., `TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion`).

As a general rule, use `await` instead of `ContinueWith`:

```
virtual internal async Task<NetworkDeviceNodeStatus[]> GetRoutersOn3GBackupNodeStatusesAsync()
{
  List<Branch3GInfo> branchActive3GInfos = new List<Branch3GInfo>();

  var nodeStatuses = new List<NetworkDeviceNodeStatus>();
  NetworkDeviceNodeStatus[] deviceStatuses = new NetworkDeviceNodeStatus[0];
  var result = GetNodesAsync();
  deviceStatuses = GetNetworkDeviceNodeStatuses(branchActive3GInfos.ToArray());
  return deviceStatuses;
}

private async Task<Branch3GInfo[]> GetNodesAsync()
{
  var result = await GetNodesOn3GBackupAsyncInternal();
  branchActive3GInfos = result.Where(y => y.Status == Branch3GInfo.Branch3GStatus.Active).ToList();
  Trace.TraceInformation("Found " + x.Result.Count() + " CAS Nodes on 3G backup.");

  foreach (var branchActive3GInfo in branchActive3GInfos) {
    await branchActive3GInfo.RouterInfo.GetBasicInfoAsync();
    Trace.TraceInformation("Retrieved ModelBasicInfo for "
            + branchActive3GInfo.RouterInfo.GetBasicInfo());
  }
  return result;
}
```